# How to further customize the Control Strip of the Touch bar (to add brightness and volume control)

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I want to add

[image]

and

[image]

to the collapsed Control Strip, so that they are always visible, but we can still make use of a dynamic Expanded Control Strip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently can't.

Best you can do is permanently set the control bar to Extended Control Bar.

`Settings > Keyboard > Touch Bar shows > Expanded Control Strip`